# QEMU emulation not giving output when executed by phyton

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi3, qemu

I'm trying to execute QEMU emulation using a python script, but it doesn't show the system output, just some warnings. If i try it by hand on the terminal it works perfect. My python code for the command is:

```
terminal_command = f'gnome-terminal -- bash -c "/home/jose/Escritorio/qemu/build/qemu-system-aarch64  -M raspi3b  -kernel /home/jose/Escritorio/Imagen/kernel8.img -sd /home/jose/Escritorio/Imagen_SO/2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-armhf-resized.img -nographic -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" -dtb Imagen/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb"'

subprocess.Popen(terminal_command, shell=True)
```

I expected getting the standard boot output from Raspbian, instead got nothing, i tried different combinations of the command -sdio, but no result.

Comment: Try debugging this using a tool called Pipe Viewer (`pv`). You may have to install it (e.g. Ubuntu, `sudo apt install pv`). Change `terminal_command` to include `| pv -b 2>/tmp/progress` before the final double-quote, then monitor the contents of `/tmp/progress` in another window during execution (`watch cat /tmp/progress`). If it stops at `0.00 B`, then the problem is in your QEMU command; if it is non-zero, the problem is in where your output is going.